# AlertDialog Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Mi duda es la siguiente:
¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que un AlertDialog se muestre siempre (aunque toques fuera del objeto o en el botón atrás) hasta que no des al botón "aceptar" o "cancelar"?

Comment: Hola Pablo da un vistazo a [ask], saludos!, Agrega lo que has tratado.

Comment: Pablo,  ¿te fue de ayuda la respuesta de @Federico Madoery?

Answer (score 9):

Para lograr esa, puedes usar lo siguiente:

> `dialog.setCancelable(false);`  Al presionar atrás, no se cierre tu dialog. - Lo contrario sucede para un valor true
>
> `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`  Al tocar fuera de la ventana del dialog, este no se cierra. - Lo contrario sucede para un valor true

Answer (score 0):

para poder evitar que el usuario haga clic en retroceder o fuera del AlertDialog solo use:

```
bottomSheet.setCancelable(false);
```

con esto el usuario tendrá que elegir entre las opciones que tiene tu Alert.