# ¿Cómo evitar el cierre de un AlertDialog al hacer touch fuera del dialogo?

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy usando el siguiente codigo para evitar que cuando el usuario haga click fuera del dialogo este se cierre, pero no funciona

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(dialogLayout)
       .setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Francisco, revisa [_**esta pregunta**_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133027/alertdialog-android-studio/133034#133034) es lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Hola Francisco, te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [AlertDialog Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133027/alertdialog-android-studio)

Comment: @Maximiliano si, pero sucede que la pregunta no tiene la respuesta aceptada, espero el OP la de como aceptada para cerrarla, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El dialogo debe estar configurado como cancelable mediante el método `setCancelable(true)`, asignando un valor `true` indica que se puede cancelar, asignando un valor `false` no se puede cancelar.

> [setCancelable(boolean cancel)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)) : Establece si este diálogo es cancelable con la
>   tecla ATRÁS.

pero si deseas que se cancele cuanto tocas afuera debes usar el método

> [setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)) Establece si este
>   diálogo se cancela cuando se toca fuera de los límites de la ventana.
>   Si se establece en verdadero, el diálogo se establece para ser
>   cancelable si no está configurado.

Por lo tanto debería realizarse de esta forma:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(dialogLayout)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

de esta forma NO se permitiría al dialogo ser cancelado cuando se toca fuera del mismo.